# Python: How to countdown a number, and append that countdown to a list

Tags: python, list, append, countdown

Here's my attempt at creating a countdown in which all the numbers get appended to a list.

```
timeleft = 3
num1 = 24 - timeleft
mylist = []


def countdown():
    while num1 != 0:
          num1 -= 1
          mylist.append(num1)

countdown()
```

This is a small section of a schedule making app I'm making.

Comment: `timeleft` is defined after it's used (Or maybe you didn't post the whole code).

Comment: Your `countdown()` function should accept one parameter, and you should pass `num1` variable as that parameter.

Comment: what is wrong with your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using global variables, I'd write a `countdown` function which accepts a `start` parameter and returns a `list` like this:

```
def countdown(start):
    return list(range(start,0,-1))
```

Demo:

```
timeleft = 3
num1 = 24 - timeleft
cd = countdown(num1)
print(cd) # [21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you want to count to zero use `range(start,-1,-1)`.

Comment: Thank you, that was so fast! I was having trouble understanding x for x in range(start,0,-1). I guess the range function is similar to a countdown?

Comment: This list comprehension is unnecessary.

Comment: @AaronHall I used it because the OP did not provide his python version and this will work in either. I think your answer is fine too (I gave it +1).

Answer (score 0):

```
def countdown(time_left):
    return [x for x in range(24 - time_left, -1, -1)]
```

Test:

```
>>> countdown(20)
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> countdown(15)
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, just return the call to range, which returns a list:

```
def countdown2(x, y=0):
    return range(x, y-1, -1)
```

In Python 3, need to materialize range in a list:

```
def countdown2(x, y=0):
    return list(range(x, y-1, -1))
```

To actually append to a list:

```
def countdown(x, y=0):
    '''countdown from x to y, return list'''
    l = []
    for i in range(x, y-1, -1): # Python 2, use xrange
        l.append(i)
    return l
```

But a direct list would be standard approach here, not a list comprehension.